# Fourier transform with matrices

Tags: calculus, fourier-analysis

Any function $f$ with $\int_\mathbf{x \in \mathbb{R}^n} |f(\mathbf{x})|<\infty$ satisfies the following property: for any nonsingular square matrix $\mathbf{T}$, if
$h(\mathbf{Tx}) = f(\mathbf{x})$ then $\hat{h}(\mathbf{y}) = det(\mathbf{T})$ $\hat{f}(\mathbf{T}^T\mathbf{y})$,
where $\hat{f}$ and $\hat{h}$ are the Fourier transforms of $f$ and $h$ respectively.

A proof for the above property first considers

$\hat{h}(\mathbf{y}) = \int_\mathbf{z \in \mathbb{R}^n}$ $h(\mathbf{z}) e^{-2\pi i \langle \mathbf{z},\mathbf{y}\rangle}$ $d \mathbf{z}$ = $\int_\mathbf{z \in \mathbb{R}^n} f(\mathbf{T}^{-1}\mathbf{z})$ $e^{-2\pi i \langle \mathbf{z},\mathbf{y}\rangle}$ $d \mathbf{z}$.

Then does a change in variable $\mathbf{z} = \mathbf{Tx}$ which leads the last expression to be equal to det($\mathbf{T}$) $\int_\mathbf{x \in \mathbb{R}^n} f(\mathbf{x})$ $e^{-2\pi i \langle \mathbf{x},\mathbf{T}^T\mathbf{y}\rangle}$ $d \mathbf{x}$.

My question is how did the change in  variables result in the det$(\mathbf{T})$ factor?

Comment: $\det (T)$ is the Jacobian of the transformation $x \to Tx$.